Replacement of integrand inside inactive integral does not work for list of rules
I have a list of rules for expanding inactive integrals, because somehow the regular mathematica functions don't work for inactive integrals.
outrules = {Inactive[Integrate][f_ + g_, it__ : {x_Symbol, __}] :> 
    Inactive[Integrate][f, it] + Inactive[Integrate][g, it], 
   Inactive[Integrate][c_ f_, it__List] :> 
    c Inactive[Integrate][f, it] /; 
     FreeQ[c, t1] && FreeQ[c, t2] && FreeQ[c, t3] && FreeQ[c, t4], 
   Inactive[Integrate][A_ (B_ + C_), range__] :> 
    Inactive[Integrate][A B + A C, range], 
   Inactive[Integrate][integrand_, range__] :> 
    Inactive[Integrate][Expand[integrand], range]};

And i have the integral on which I apply the replacement. for me the first line produces no effect while the second line works. Can anyone reproduce this?
1/2 h^3 Sy^5 \[CapitalOmega]^5 Inactive[Integrate][
   E^(-2 I t1)
     Inactive[Integrate][E^(
     2 I t2), {t2, 0, t1}]^2 Inactive[
      Integrate][-(1/2) I E^(-I t2) (-1 + E^(2 I t2)), {t2, 0, 
      t1}], {t1, 0, 2 \[Pi]}] //. outrules
1/2 h^3 Sy^5 \[CapitalOmega]^5 Inactive[Integrate][
   E^(-2 I t1)
     Inactive[Integrate][E^(
     2 I t2), {t2, 0, t1}]^2 Inactive[
      Integrate][-(1/2) I E^(-I t2) (-1 + E^(2 I t2)), {t2, 0, 
      t1}], {t1, 0, 2 \[Pi]}] //. outrules[[3]]


This kind of thing sometimes occurs when one of the previous rules matches first each pass through, and so it never sees the later rule in the list. It's worth checking your expression to see if it matches each left-hand side directly using MatchQ first before replacing.  That's how I usually troubleshoot these issues. I'm checking it at the moment.

If you get rid of the last rule in outrules, applying //. outrules seems to work. Indeed, that rule always matches; that doesn't seem like it should be an issue, because it's the last rule in the list and should be checked last.  I'm still trying to understand it.

but how do you check it with MatchQ? I am trying to check the second rule but I cannot

For instance, MatchQ[Inactive[Integrate][-(1/2) I E^(-I t2) (-1 + E^(2 I t2)), {t2, 0, t1}] ,Inactive[Integrate][A_ (B_ + C_), range__]] yields True.

Sometimes it's hard to understand complicated sets of rules applied to complicated expressions, since one can get lost trying to figure out just which part is failing and why. In this case the "simple principles" that explain the behavior are that

when a part of an expression matches a pattern in a rule, the subexpressions of the part are not transform (in ReplaceAll)

and

when a set of rules is applied and there is no change, ReplaceRepeated stops.

Rules ##1–3 do not match the outer integral but rule #4 matches the outer integral; however, rule #4 does not transform the outer integral, so ReplaceRepeated stops after the first try.
While a workaround is not explicitly sought, experience shows that users care less about "why?" than they thought they did when they asked, once a workaround is presented. I would guess they would care even less about whether "can anyone reproduce this?" than about "why?"
To address the issue above, check that Expand[integrand] in rule #4 actually makes a change:
outrules = {
   Inactive[Integrate][f_ + g_, it__ : {x_Symbol, __}] :> 
    Inactive[Integrate][f, it] + Inactive[Integrate][g, it],
   Inactive[Integrate][c_ f_, it__List] :> 
    c Inactive[Integrate][f, it] /; 
     FreeQ[c, t1] && FreeQ[c, t2] && FreeQ[c, t3] && FreeQ[c, t4],
   Inactive[Integrate][integrand_, range__] :> 
    With[{exp = Expand[integrand]}, 
     Inactive[Integrate][exp, range] /; exp =!= integrand]};

1/2 h^3 Sy^5 \[CapitalOmega]^5 Inactive[Integrate][
   E^(-2 I t1) Inactive[Integrate][E^(2 I t2), {t2, 0, t1}]^2 *
    Inactive[Integrate][-(1/2) I E^(-I t2) (-1 + E^(2 I t2)), {t2, 0, 
      t1}], {t1, 0, 2 \[Pi]}] //. outrules

I took out rule #3, but you can keep it in if you like.
Debugging. Sometimes it can help to trace which rules are getting used and how. Applying Echo[..., tag] can be helpful, when Trace[] may yield TMI. I verified my understanding of the "simple principles" above with the following:
outrules = {
   Inactive[Integrate][f_ + g_, it__ : {x_Symbol, __}] :>
    Echo[Inactive[Integrate][f, it] + Inactive[Integrate][g, it], 1],
   Inactive[Integrate][c_ f_, it__List] :>
    Echo[c Inactive[Integrate][f, it], 2] /;
     FreeQ[c, t1] && FreeQ[c, t2] && FreeQ[c, t3] && FreeQ[c, t4],
   Inactive[Integrate][A_ (B_ + C_), range__] :>
    Echo[Inactive[Integrate][A B + A C, range], 3],
   Inactive[Integrate][integrand_, range__] :>
    Echo[Inactive[Integrate][Expand[integrand], range], 4]};



thank you. so is it correct that the outer expressions are checked first for every rule and since there is no transformations, replace repeated stops before checking the inner integrals. is there a way to make it check the inner expressions too before stopping?
with your new rule it should not be able to make a match without a transformation, so it should work, (my rule 3 and 4 should do the same thing but I only included them because I didn't know that rule 4 was matching and doing nothing)

but also there must be a reason it doesnt work with //.outrules but it does work with //.outrules[[3]] . Is it because rule 3 does not match the outer expressions but rule 4 does and causes replacerepeated to stop, whereas if I only apply rule 3 it will keep searching the sub expressions too?

Re #1: You could Map the rules to the lower levels (seems tricky) or use recursion: Add to outrules: Inactive[Integrate][integrand_, range__] :>   Inactive[Integrate][Expand[integrand] /. outrules, range]. Re #2: That is correct.
